# vs2015 - Icon didn't really change

Tags: c#, visual-studio

So i've set my first icon few weeks back, this morning i changed the icon with a new one.. and i rebuilt my solution.. so i checked the output files in the Debug folder, i found out that my icon didn't really changed.. When the explorer's view was "medium-sized icons", the new icon appeared.. see the screenshot in medium-sized icons view..
[image: Medium-sized icons]

then i tried enlarging the view to "Large icons", my icon turned into the old one.. See the screenshot in Large icons view..
[image: Large icons]

Comment: Did you tried this http://www.vistax64.com/general-discussion/286459-different-images-small-medium-icons-windows-explorer.html

Comment: The icons are cached. Try restarting your computer.

Comment: Yes i did, but it didn't work..
@BarmakShemirani i did, many times..

Comment: @Vidya It didn't work